# Umlaut in username: .UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 235: invalid continuation byte

Tags: windows, docker, utf-8, ddev

I'm currently running in such a tricky error. I'm running ddev on Windows 10.
It seems, the problem is my name "André Kraus", because of the "é" inside.
In the past it works fine with a [path-to-project]/.ddev/docker-compose.environment.yaml, set my username to "andrekraus"

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
  db:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
```

But since yesterday, there occurs a new challenge. When I type in ddev start it ends up with:

```
$ ddev start
Starting ddev-test-4...
.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 235: invalid continuation byte
Failed to start ddev-test-4: failed to start ddev-ssh-agent: Failed to run docker-compose [-f C:\Users\André Kraus/.ddev/.ssh-auth-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-ssh-agent up --build --force-recreate -d], err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 235: invalid continuation byte'
```

I tried to fix that in my docker-compose.environment.yaml with

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
  db:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
  ddev-ssh-agent:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
```

but this didn't effect anything.
The problem occurs for sure in the C:\Users\André Kraus.ddev.ssh-auth-composer-full.yaml (screenshot) in my user directory, but how can I manage the settings there?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3Bf.png)

Comment: The error says that the `.ssh-auth-compose-full.yaml` file is not saved using `utf-8` encoding…

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, you are right. But solving that isn't easy.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2021-09-27** This is fixed and shouldn't occur in ddev v1.18.0+. However... it may not be possible to handle spaces and related unusual situations in the user homedir. Where possible, always use ASCII characters for usernames and don't have spaces in key identifiers like usernames.

### Fix the utf-8 Problem:

Overwrite the name in the [path-to-project]/.ddev/docker-compose.env.yaml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
  db:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
```

Then in ~/.ddev (in my example on Windows it is C:\Users\André Kraus.ddev ) create new the file ssh-auth-compose.environment.yaml:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  ddev-ssh-agent:
    build:
      args:
        username: andrekraus
```

This solves the problem with the username, but I didn't get the path working. So at the moment, I omit the ddev-ssh-agent.

### Omit the ddev-ssh-agent

Add my configuration to the config, create new file [path-to-project]/.ddev/config.user.yaml:

```
omit_containers: [ddev-ssh-agent]
```

### Clear restart needed for ddev

So after that, I had some issues to get it working again. I did `ddev poweroff` and then `docker ps -a`. The list shows some containers running, I had to stop them all (`docker-compose down` in the project directories) so that `docker ps -a` shows an empty list.

After that, `ddev start` works again.

### Thank you so much [@rfay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215713/rfay) for your help!